# Remove array key from array in cakephp

Tags: arrays, cakephp

print array

```
array(
    'Order' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'base_price' => '65',
        'min_price' => '95',            
    )
)
```

Is it possible to remove the key('Order') when you retrieving data? if Not how can I use array_shift or end in one line and to prevent below error?

I am getting this error `Only variables should be passed by reference` when I remove the key from array.

```
$orders = array_shift or end ($this->Order->read(null, $id));
debug($orders);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want only id from it then following code will help you

```
 $arrOrderId=Set::extract("/Order/id",$data);
```

here $data is your array from where you want to delete this "Order" key.

You will get following array when you do `debug($arrOrderId);`

```
[0]=>1
```

if you want base_price then write following code

```
$arrOrderId=Set::extract("/Order/base_price",$data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Set` functions for manipulating arrays:

```
Set::extract($array, 'Order');
```

Will output:

```
array(
    'id' => '1',
    'base_price' => '65',
    'min_price' => '95',            
)
```

If you need to do this on every output, you can override `afterFind()` method on your model.

Please see the docs:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::extract

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::classicExtract