# Cakephp get all value with comma separated?

Tags: arrays, cakephp

Its a very basic php question, I want to display a value with comma separated from.I know a procedure,I can get comma separated value by using comma explode. I just want to confirm will it run successfully or not.I am giving my output and array below : I need my output something like **Sahbaj,test-name**.

**And my array :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [AdoPosition] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Sahbaj
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [AdoPosition] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test-name
                )

        )

)
```

**My controller code is below :**

```
$name = $this->AdoPosition->find('all',
     array(
       'fields'=>'AdoPosition.name',
       'group'=>'AdoPosition.name'
       ));  
pr($name);
```

Comment: Basic PHP: foreach() or Hash::extract() + implode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do that:

```
$name = $this->AdoPosition->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('AdoPosition.name', 'AdoPosition.name'),
    'group' => array('AdoPosition.name')
));
$name = implode(',', $name);
```

The return is:

```
"Sahbaj,test-name"
```

Answer (score 1):

make it simple

```
$names=Set::extract("/AdoPosition/name",$array);
```

OR

```
$names = $this->AdoPosition->find('list', array('fields'=>array('name')));
```

look at this.
[Remove array key from array in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559289/remove-key-from-array-on-retrieveing-data-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to ask mysql to join with comma like-

```
$data = $this->AdoPosition->query('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name) from your_table_name;');
```

Answer (score 0):

For better efficiency try this.

```
$result = implode( ",", Set::classicExtract($name, '{n}.AdoPosition.name'));

echo $result; // Sahbaj,test-name
```