# how to remove indexes form an array in php?

Tags: arrays, cakephp

I am looking to except single element from array. My array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [COUNT(ID)] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

I have already use PHP functions `basename` and `array_shift`, but they didn't give me proper value. I want only single string `COUNT(ID)` value.

Here is my function using in cakephp model:

```
$res = $this->query("select COUNT(ID) from users where Username = '".$Username['Username']."'");
if ($res[0][0]['COUNT(ID)'] >= 1)
{
    return false; 
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

I don't need `$res[0][0]`, I need only `COUNT[ID]`. Is there any easy way to find only `COUNT[ID]`.

Comment: access it just like any other nested (associative) array

Comment: `$a[0][0]['COUNT(ID)']` ?

Comment: Why are you creating a manual query in Cake? It's built to return data like that...

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions given below?? There isn't any reply from you there!!

Comment: @centiva-madhavi This is not how it is done in CakePHP! Use the answer from Shaunak Shukla or remove the cakephp tag (as this is then just PHP/MYSQL).

Comment: SQL injection vulnerabilities, SQL injection vulnerabilities everywhere...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using CakePHP, it's good to use model and inbuilt functions to get answer what you want...

```
$this->loadModel('User');    //If you are in controller
$total = $this->User->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array('Username' => $Username['Username'])
));
```

You'll get answer in single variable..!!

Answer (score 0):

Your output is produced by code like this

```
$data = array(
    array(
        array(
            'COUNT(ID)' => 0
        )
    )
);
```

You can access its value by calling directly

```
$data[0][0]['COUNT(ID)']
```

This could be [wrong problem you are solving](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), as it seems like database query result that should not look like that and could be done with more ease. You should show your original function/problem, that this script is part of.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you array's name is `$myArray`, than you can assign the value of `$myArray[0][0]['COUNT(ID)']` to `$value` in the way you usually assign a value: `$value = $myArray[0][0]['COUNT(ID)'];`.

If you want to delete an index from an array, use `unset()` like this: `unset($myArray[0][0]['COUNT(ID)'])`. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact count of nesting in array you can just access it with indexes

```
$array[0][0]['COUNT(ID)']
```

If no, you might want to use the function which will recursively find you the first nested element that is not an array

```
function getStringFromArray($array) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                return getStringFromArray($value);
            } else {
                return $value;
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Not an array given");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that array structure will remain same then this could be useful :-

```
function array_values_recursive($ary)
 {
   $lst = array();
    foreach( array_keys($ary) as $k ){
      $v = $ary[$k];
      if (is_scalar($v)) {
         $lst[] = $v;
      } elseif (is_array($v)) {
     $lst = array_merge( $lst,
        array_values_recursive($v)
     );
   }
 }
 return $lst;
}

 $arr=array(array(array('COUNT(ID)'=>5)));
 $res=array_values_recursive($arr);
 echo '<pre>';print_r($res);
```

output    :-

```
Array
 (
  [0] => 5
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fetch it by associative array to reduce dimension but you can remove index. May be you can use foreach to automatically use indexs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public $uses = array('User');
$count = $this->User->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array('Username' => $Username['Username'])
        ));
if ($count >= 1) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following technique for your solution. i did not get you what you want to do with your array but you can try below solution

```
$arr = Set::extract("/0/COUNT(ID)",$data);
```

where $data is your input array.

you will get following output

```
Array
(
  [0] => 5
)
```

you can refer below link

[Remove array key from array in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559289/remove-key-from-array-on-retrieveing-data-cakephp/22559772#22559772)